# Finding bounds of $D_p$-function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am trying to find the upper and lower bounds of the $D_p$ function, defined as:
$$
D_p(x) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^p \right)^{1/p}
$$
for $0<p<1$ and $x \in \{x=(x_1,..,x_n) | x_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i =1\} $. Is there a simpler way of doing this than setting up the lagrangian?

Comment: In your constraints, don't you want $x_i \ge 0$ instead ?

Comment: @dohmatob yes, edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_p(x)$ is concave by the reverse Minkowski inequality. Your constraint is exactly the set of $x_i$ on a simplex.

It's really not so bad with a Lagrangian. For starters, you can use $D_p^p(x)$ instead. Then the lagrange equations read:

$$px_i^{p-1}=\lambda,$$

giving $x_i=(\lambda/p)^{1/p}$ (remember $x_i\geq 0$), so summing this gives $n(\lambda/p)^{1/p}=1$ or $\lambda=\frac{p}{n^{p}}$ and $x=1/n$. You can check that this is a maximum.

For the minimum, think about $x_1=1$ and $x_i=0$ for all other $i$.

Comment: is the maximum invariant ? so maximizing $D^p$ and taking it to the power of $1/p$ is the same as maximizing $D$, does this always hold?

Comment: @Alex R.: You should consider providing the asker with a reference to the "reverse Minkowski inequality".